# Python Google Drive storage quota

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I work with the Google Drive API and Python >3.5 and I would like to get the storage quota.

The REST API is here [Link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about)

My code so far looks like this. Can you help me to query the API using the service object?

```
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata']
creds = None

tokenFile = 'path/to/token.pickle'
if os.path.exists(tokenFile):
    with open(tokenFile, 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

about_metadata = {
'fields': 'storageQuota'
}
#service.about().get(about_metadata)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve `storageQuota` from the method of "About" in Drive API v3.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been able to get values from Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

about_metadata = {
'fields': 'storageQuota'
}
#service.about().get(about_metadata)
```

To:

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

res = service.about().get(fields='storageQuota').execute()
print(res)
```

#### Reference:

- [About](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I have been looking for! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Markus Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.